# How do I put footnotes at the bottom of the page, instead of the bibliography, using the AIP template (revtex4)?

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, templates, revtex

This is a minimum working example from the [AIP template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submission-to-aip-publishing-journals/xhsskcchtbxf):

```
\documentclass[%
aip,
amsmath,amssymb,
reprint
]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
    This is the body.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
    \bibliography{aipsamp}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.   
\end{document}
```

What happens is that when it compiles, it puts the footnote in the bibliography, when I want the footnote to show up at the bottom of the column or page.
[image: Compiled Document]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the `nofootinbib` option to `\documentclass`.  E.g.,

```
\documentclass[%
    aip,
    amsmath,amssymb,
    reprint,
    nofootinbib
]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
This is the body.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
This is a citation: \cite{feyn54}.
\bibliography{aipsamp}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.   
\end{document}
```

This is documented in the `summary4-1.pdf` (or `summary4-2.pdf`) file in the documentation directory for revtex.

The above document has the disadvantage that references to footnotes and to the bibliography both have the form of superscript numbers. So you would probably want to change the citation style.  An easy way to do this is to change the option `aip` to the option for a different journal, e.g., to `aps`.

Comment: That works, though if I have to change the citation style to a different journal, it might mean I won't be able to publish to AIP.

Comment: If you publish with the AIP (or the APS) they'll use whatever style the journal uses in the published version. You may have a choice: For example, J Math Phys allows either numerical citations, with footnotes in the same list as references, or author-year citations with conventional footnotes.  Using different options to the document class than the standard ones for a journal is a trivial change to make.  You can always make a different choice when you are editing the paper.